# How to get ObjectID from update with upsert option in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

It's possible to get last automatically generated `ObjectID` from `update` method with `upsert` option?
Something like `LAST_INSERT_ID()` in mysql.

Here the example code:

```
/**
 * MongoDB ver. 2.4.9
 * MongoDB NodeJS Driver ver. 1.3.23
 */
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/learning', function(err, db) {
    var c = db.collection('testUpsert');
    c.insert({a: true}, function(err, result) {
        // Here I can reach `_id` field
        console.dir(result); // object with id
    });
    c.update({ _id: undefined }, {a: false}, {upsert: true, w: 1}, function(err, result) {
        // Any elegant way to fetch `_id` of new document here?
        console.dir(result); // 1
    });
});
```

Comment: Doesn't the findAndModify (http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/markdown-docs/insert.html#find-and-modify) work?

Comment: Yes! Exactly what I need. Thanks, @joao.  
Following code works for me:  
`c.findAndModify({ _id: undefined }, [], {a: false}, {upsert: true, new: true}, function(err, result) {...}`